# When removing a child from list, it deletes the parent as well

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I have two classes User and Task. When I remove a child from list, I just want to delete that child, instead it deletes the parent as well. I want to keep the parent(User) but want to remove a child(Tasks list) from list.

User class:

```
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "users",
        uniqueConstraints = {
                @UniqueConstraint(name = "unq_email_users", columnNames = "email")
        })
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false)
    private String email;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_users"))
    private List<Task> tasks = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Task class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tasks")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class Task {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnore
    private User user;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Task{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", title='" + title + '\'' +
                ", description='" + description + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Here is a service method I am using to remove child from list:

```
public User removeUserTask(Long userId, Long taskId) {
        Optional<User> userOptional = userRepository.findById(userId);
        if(!userOptional.isPresent()) {
            throw new NotFoundException("No User Found With Id - " + userId);
        }

        User user = userOptional.get();
        Task task1 = user.getTasks().stream().filter(task -> task.getId().equals(userId)).findFirst().orElse(null);
        if(task1==null) {
            throw new NotFoundException("No Task Found With Id - " + taskId);
        }
        user.getTasks().remove(task1);
        userRepository.save(user);
        return user;
    }
```

But surprisingly it removes parent as well.

What I am trying to do is to remove just task from its table, but when I remove a task it deletes the parent and other tasks as well. Was not *orphanRemoval = true* supposed to removed just those tasks which are not associated to a user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you told hibernate to cascade the changes by using `cascade = CascadeType.ALL`. If you don't want to delete parent, you need to remove it or provide an array with `CascageType`s other than `CascadeType.REMOVE`, for example:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = {
    CascadeType.PERSIST,
    CascadeType.MERGE
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out, I was using `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` in both entities, so deleting a **`Task`** was automatically deleting the **`User`**, I have changed

```
cascade = CascadType.All
```

to

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
```

on Task entity and it is working fine.

Comment: this was not repetition actually we commented at the same time